# Unity - error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem when trying to build a unity project in Web GL. I am currently using the unity playground script + two of my own design. Here's my script, can anybody tell me what/where the problem is? Thank you!

Error:UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in <90d4bcb003fb405fb09241aed2f178aa>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <90d4bcb003fb405fb09241aed2f178aa>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

My scripts:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour { 

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool isGrounded;

    public Transform feetPos;

    public float checkRadius, jumpForce, moveInput, speed, jumpTimeCounter,jumpTime;

    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool isJumping;
    private Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
        if(moveInput == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning",false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }else if(moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        }

        if(isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping==true)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
              rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                isJumping = false;
            }

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is all over the place, and that error indicates most likely a syntax error or missing import/type error - are you using an IDE? If not, you should be, it will instantly highlight problems like that. Either way, this error is a symptom, not a cause - you should have other errors showing up in the editor too, address those first and this one will go away.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio, but the IDE doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Tip for you: Hit Ctrl+K, then Ctrl+D in Visual Studio. Consistent code is readable code. That aside, the error clearly says the *scripts have compile errors*, those compile errors should be showing up as separate errors in the output area. Those are the actual problem.

Comment: I will take a further look into the code once again, thank you for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it: The problem was not in my code, but I had to remove the XR Legacy Input Helpers package in order for the game to build! You can do that by going to Window > Package Manager, scroll down to XR Legacy Input Helpers, select it and click Remove.